# How to break a loop from an outside function

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is how can you break from outside a loop. If i can't is there a work around?

```
def breaker(numberOfTimesYouWantToBreak):
    for i in range(0,numberOfTimesYouWantToBreak+1):
        return break
while True:
    for i in range(0,100000):
        breaker(10)
        print(i)
```

The result i want is:

```
11,12,13,14...
```

Comment: You cannot return a `break` statement from another function. Besides, there is no such thing as breaking more than once.

Comment: Is there a work around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use the `break` statement anywhere else but directly in the loop. You cannot return it from another function, it is not an object to be passed around.

You appear to want to **skip**, not break from the loop, however. You are looking for the `continue` keyword instead:

```
for i in range(0,100000):
    if i < 10:
        continue
    print(i)
```

If you must use a separate function, then have that function return `True` or `False` and use an `if` test to conditionally use `continue`:

```
def should_skip(i):
    return i < 10

for i in range(0,100000):
    if should_skip(i):
        continue
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible.

The workaround is to put your code into a function and `return` from the function.

Comment: Thanks this is also useful i will know next time!

Answer (score 0):

You can't break externally, however, for the same effect you can do this:

```
for i in range(0,100000):
    i += 10 + 1 #(10 is the number you wanted in the break function)
    print(i)
```