# Python - breaking a loop from an outside function

Tags: python, multithreading, for-loop, animation

I want to control the execution of some functions, through using some buttons in `matplolib`.
I want to pause the execution of a function, which is in my case to break the for loop, for that I used the following in my script:

```
def pause(mouse_event):
    global pauseVal
    pauseVal ^= True

def play(mouse_event):    
    for x in range(int(dataSlider.val),len(listOfMomentsVis)):
        if pauseVal == True:
            break
        else:
            image.set_data(listOfMomentsVis[x]) 
            fig.canvas.draw()
            dataSlider.set_val(x+1)
            time.sleep(timeSleep)
            print(x)
```

What's happening is the that the function would not execute the next time I try to execute it, not **during the execution**. In other words, the `pause` button won't be effective until the next execution.

My question is: how to break the for loop in the middle of execution through an outside button event? 
Is that doable or should be some other way? (Could make the for loop `listen` to the outside function?!)

PS: I found the following question with the same title, [How to break a loop from an outside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383898/how-to-break-a-loop-from-an-outside-function), however, the answers were about breaking according to a value in the loop, not a value from outside.

**updae**

Here is my update version of the script. I took the comments and answers into consideration, made a class, still not getting the desired results.

```
class animationButtons():
    def __init__(self):
        self.pauseVal = False

    def backward(self, mouse_event):
        ref = int(dataSlider.val)
        if ref-1<0:
            print('error')
        else:
            image.set_data(listOfMomentsVis[ref-1])
            dataSlider.set_val(ref-1)

    def forward(self, mouse_event):
        ref = int(dataSlider.val)
        if ref+1>len(listOfMomentsVis):
            ref = int(dataSlider.val)-1
            print('error')
        else:
            image.set_data(listOfMomentsVis[ref])
            dataSlider.set_val(ref+1)
            print('from forward', dataSlider.val)

    def play(self, mouse_event):
        for x in range(int(dataSlider.val),len(listOfMomentsVis)):
            ref = int(dataSlider.val)
            dataSlider.set_val(ref+1)
            time.sleep(timeSleep)
            print('from play',ref)
            if self.pauseVal:
                break

    def playReverse(self, mouse_event):
        for x in range(int(dataSlider.val),0,-1):
            ref = int(dataSlider.val)
            dataSlider.set_val(ref-1)
            time.sleep(timeSleep)
            print('from play',ref)
            if self.pauseVal:
                break

    def pause(self, mouse_event):
        self.pauseVal ^= True
        print(self.pauseVal)

    def animate(self, val):
        ref = int(dataSlider.val)
        image.set_data(listOfMomentsVis[ref])
        print('from animate',ref)
        fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Sounds like your problem really lies in the fact that you're executing everything in a single thread. You'd generally need a separate thread that handles mouse clicks (and other UI actions). In that case, your solution should work (ish).

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks from a GUI event handler should complete quick, otherwise they hold up the thread responsible for processing events. This means you cannot do things like: `time.sleep(timeSleep)` in the callback function.

Instead you can use a timer to periodically trigger an animation event and then get your play and pause buttons to stop and start the timer. The following example creates a moving sine wave that stops after it has moved one full wavelength. Pressing play triggers the animation if one is not already in progress, or resumes if there is a currently paused animation. Pause pauses the animation if one is currently playing.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2) # add space for buttons

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

class Example:

    steps = 200

    def __init__(self):
        self.step_index = 0
        self.timer = None

    def animate(self):
        print(self.step_index)
        # update the data
        line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + (2 * np.pi * self.step_index / self.steps)))
        self.step_index += 1
        plt.draw()        

        # stop if end of animation
        if self.step_index >= self.steps:
            self.timer = None
            return False

    def play(self, event):
        if not self.timer:
            # no current animation, start a new one.
            self.timer = fig.canvas.new_timer(interval=10)
            self.timer.add_callback(self.animate)
            self.step_index = 0
        self.timer.start()

    def pause(self, event):
        if not self.timer:
            return
        self.timer.stop()

ex = Example()
ax_pause = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
ax_play = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
pause_button = Button(ax_pause, 'Pause')
pause_button.on_clicked(ex.pause)
play_button = Button(ax_play, 'Play')
play_button.on_clicked(ex.play)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried to do something similar in my updated version of the code, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work as more of an OOP approach....

```
class ClasName():
    # Add any variables you want to keep track of...
    def __init__(self, dataSlider, listOfMomentsVis):
        self.paseVal = False
        self.dataSlider = dataSlider
        self.listOfMomentsVis = listOfMomentsVis 

    # Your methods to manipulate the class instance variables
    def pause(self, mouse_event):
        self.pauseVal ^= True

    def play(self, mouse_event):    
        for x in range(int(self.dataSlider.val),len(self.listOfMomentsVis)):
            if self.pauseVal == True:
                # Reset the pauseVal state
                self.pauseVal ^= False
                break

            else:
                image.set_data(listOfMomentsVis[x]) 
                fig.canvas.draw()
                dataSlider.set_val(x+1)
                time.sleep(timeSleep)
                print(x)
```

Comment: I tried to do something similar in my updated version of the code, still not working.